# Include PHP e diretórios?

Tags: php, html

$url = "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ;

Resultado = localhost/dashboard/folders/teste/florianopolis.php

Esse código acima me mostra tudo, inclusive o nome do arquivo. Tem algum método de não mostrar o arquivo?

Assim que gostaria que ficasse = localhost/dashboard/folders/teste/

**FILE** me mostra esse resultado = http:///Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dashboard/folders/teste/footer.php

**DIR** me mostra esse resultado = http:///Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dashboard/folders/teste/

Eu não quero o caminho completo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/, quero somente localhost/dashboard/folders/teste/

Porque isso servirá tanto para o server online quanto pro offline.

Alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

PS: Editei a pergunta anterior, assim acho que ficou mais claro!

Comment: Qual a versão do PHP?

Comment: teria como anexar um pint da estrutura de pasta do seu projeto?

Comment: Por quê não quer utilizar o caminho absoluto sendo que resolve seu problema?

Comment: Versão do PHP é 5.3

Comment: Não utilizo o caminho absoluto porque esse site tem em vários domínios e não gostaria de ficar editando o caminho absoluto para cada domínio.

Comment: Estrutura atualizada conforme projeto.

Answer (score 2):

Para manter um caminho relativo você deve sempre subir para o diretório raiz, e depois procurar o arquivo a ser incluído.

Existem várias formas de fazer isso.

**$_SERVER**

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

**Constantes mágicas**

```
__DIR__
```

**Acesso pelo include**

```
./
```

etc...

Cada um com suas particularidades, como listagem a partir do documento atual, e também variações de destino por sistema operacional

ai é só concatenar com seu destino e esse caminho será sempre usado, idependentemente do diretório

Comment: Uma pergunta besta: essa solução vai servir tanto para o servidor (exemplo GoDaddy) como para o easyphp?

Comment: Se estiver de acordo com a versão do php, vai sim sem problemas

Comment: Felipe,

Como eu coloco isso no <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> que está no footer?

Não estou conseguindo de maneira nenhuma. Pode me ajudar por favor?

Comment: Seguite tente <script src="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/suaPastaPrincipal/'; ?>js/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: olhe no console do navegador para ver aonde ele está apontando, desse modo é só ir arrumando as pastas até encontrar

Comment: Oi Felipe!
Primeiramente muito obrigado pela sua ajuda!

Sem querer ser chato mas já sendo... Existe a possibilidade do php pegar a url absoluta exatamente do arquivo footer.php?

No exemplo que você me mandou, ele funciona online sem problemas, mas já no server off, não funciona porque entre o root e o arquivo existem diretorios (Uso o XAMPP).

Isso aqui: .$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

me mostra tudo, inclusive o nome do arquivo. Tem algum método de não mostrar o arquivo?

Comment: Esse é o echo do código acima:

https://localhost/dashboard/folders/teste/florianopolis.php

Queria que ficasse assim:

https://localhost/dashboard/folders/teste/

Comment: não entendi mt bem, mas __DIR__ mostra o diretório onde seu arquivo está, abstendo o arquivo é claro

Comment: "_ _DIR_ _", caso sua versão do php não seja compativel use dirname(_ _FILE_ _), como o site aqui exclui o nome das constantes segue o link de apoio http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: Felipe, atualizei o post, acho que agora está mais fácil de entender. Novamente obrigado.

Comment: Entendi, tente isso

Comment: $url = explode('/', "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
unset($url[(count($url) - 1)]);
$url = implode('/', $url) . '/';